# It seems, that method is called twice, when collision happens . cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, spritebuilder

I use this code to show game over menu after `_hero` sprite and `_enemy` sprite collide :

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_hero.boundingBox,_enemy.boundingBox)) {
    CCActionCallFunc *_callShowMenu=[CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showMenu)];
    [self runAction:_callShowMenu];

   // EDIT : I also remove both sprites when collision happens.

   [_hero removeFromParent];
   [_enemy removeFromParent];
}
```

In `_callShowMenu` I just stop all actions and show a sprite with half transparent black background image and buttons.
Sometimes when collision happens, it seems to me, that `_callShowMenu` is called twice, because 
background is completely black, like there is the same image behind. Has anyone had a similar problem? (Mostly background image is half-transparent, as it should be).

EDIT:

```
-(void)showMenu{
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    CCSprite *_halfTransparentBackground=[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"halfTransparentBackground.png"];
    _halfTransparentBackground.position=ccp(160, 280);
    [self addChild:_blackBack z:5]; 


}
```

Comment: Why use `CCActionCallFunc` at all? Why not call `[self _callShowMenu]` directly?

Comment: did you verify how many times it is called ? 'being called twice' could very well be a 'solution' looking for a 'problem to solve', ie the dark background could be dark for some other (valid) reason you have not foreseen.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I just can't see other reason, why half-transaprent image(not bade half-transaprent by code) can become not transparent. I suspected that's because of physics(maybe it gets collision twice, but I remove both one of sprites at once after collision..).

Comment: @Droppy Xcode shows issue in this case('No visible interface declares the selector bla bla bla')

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Than why is it called twice not always, only from time to time?

Comment: Did you put an NSLog trace to ascertain it gets called multiple times ?

Comment: Sorry my comment should have said `[self showMenu]`.

Comment: @Droppy Right.Sorry, I should sight.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I found solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using BOOL. Actually everyone uses BOOL in this case, so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

```
BOOL doNotCallMeTwice;
```

Somewhere in the `didLoad` method:

```
 doNotCallMeTwice=NO;
```

In the collision detection method:

```
if (doNotCallMeTwice==NO) {
              [self showMenu];
        }
```

And finally:

```
-(void)showMenu{
 doNotCallMeTwice=YES;
}
```

Possibly, `showMenu` was called twice(or much more times),because collision detection is in the update method.